# Amplitude Spectrum, Nyquist Frequency, mixed/min/max wavelets

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing, filters, wavelets

The problem is [here](http://i.gyazo.com/5e14f0b8266e74eb8850fa831b5e035e.png). Now I know the definition of mixed/max/min phase wavelets, whether the roots lie within the unit circle or not. Starting from n = 1, let
$$ x_t = ( 5, 6) $$ 
$$ X(z) = 5 + 6z $$
This would have root -5/6, making it a max phase wavelet (since it's within unit circle). If we switch 5 and 6 around in xt, we would get root -6/5, which would make it a min phase wavelet.

I don't know how I would show they have same amplitude spectrum. I know |X(f)| amplitude spectrum would lie between -fc and fc (Nyquist frequency) and fc = 1/2*delta t. Not sure how I would go about proving it.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have time-domain representations of these wavelets? If so, can you take their Fourier transform and show that they are equal?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is related to the fact that the spectrum is defined to be $$|W(t,u)|^2$$ and because it is related only with the magnitudes and not the phase of the transformation then their spectra will always be the same. Aside from that I don't understand very well.